# gensim model KeyError

Tags: python, gensim

I do not understand why words are not present in gensim model vocabulary after training

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1, size=200, iter=1)
print "AMBER" in sentences
vec = model.wv["AMBER"]
print vec
```

gives the following

True

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 38, in <module>
    vec = model.wv["AMBER"]
  File "/Users/nadiia/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    return self.word_vec(words)
  File "/Users/nadiia/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 288, in word_vec
    raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
KeyError: "word 'AMBER' not in vocabulary"
```

I do not understand why...
I am specifically running this model to learn embeddings of every word in list *sentences*, but then I cannot find any word in model's vocabulary. I cannot get any embeddings.

What's wrong with it?

Thanks

EDIT:
This helped to solve the problem

```
text = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent.decode("utf-8")) for sent in sentences]
```

Comment: Could it be in lower-case: `model.wv["amber"]`?

Comment: @alecxe nope.. :(

Comment: Okay, would it be possible to dump the `model.wv` and inspect what is the contents?

Comment: @alecxe I resolved the issue with utf-8 decoding..

Comment: The decoding didn't resolve the issue - the tokenization did. `Word2Vec` expects not plain-string texts, but lists-of-tokens. If your `sentences` contained `"AMBER"`, then when the string `"AMBER"` was given as an example to `Word2Vec` it will have been seen as the list of `['A', 'M', 'B', 'E', 'R']` – so the word `"AMBER"` would never have been known to the model, but the letters `"A"` or `"M"` (etc) would.